# ng-bind-html not working for data from parse

Tags: angularjs

I am building an app in angular.js with the data from parse, I am trying to display the data without html tags and I am using:

```
<p ng-bind-html="item.get('Content') | limitTo: 100"></p>
```

But nothing is being displayed, if i use:

```
<p>{{item.get('Content')}}</p>
```

The data is displayed but with html tags.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I used:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

As a dependency and that solved it thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.filter('trustAsHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
  return function(text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}])

.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.htmls = [
    "<a href='javascript:alert(1)'>1</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(2)'>2</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(4)'>4</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(8)'>8</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(16)'>16</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(32)'>32</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(64)'>64</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(128)'>128</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(256)'>256</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(512)'>512</a>",
    "<a href='javascript:alert(1024)'>1024</a>"
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <p ng-repeat="html in htmls | limitTo:9" ng-bind-html="html | trustAsHtml">
  </p>
</div>
```